# Websocket connecting failed in browser

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, websocket

I am trying to connect to websocket in browser and it's giving me

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebsite.com:9090/' failed:
```

But if i try to connect it with command prompt using

```
telnet mywebsite.com 9090
```

Then it's giving black screen in command prompt.

onError event returning following data

```
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: WebSocket {url: 'wss://learn.launchpadlearning.ca:9090/', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: WebSocket {url: 'wss://learn.launchpadlearning.ca:9090/', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
target: WebSocket {url: 'wss://learn.launchpadlearning.ca:9090/', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
timeStamp: 32264.29999999993
type: "error"
```

onClose giving code 1006 null reson

website is running on aws ec2 instance

Comment: Please show the code you used to create the websocket server. What you described sounds like maybe the port is open but it isn't adhering to the websocket protocol properly. But that's just speculation really - we need to see [mre] of the issue before we can help you accurately. See also [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: I am https://github.com/allwaysoft/simple-php-chat-using-websocket this. Localhost is working fine but not my site. I just change the hostname

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? Maybe your webhost blocks the port? Or maybe SSL is wrong or something. In the error message `WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebsite.com:9090/' failed: `, it looks like there should be more information after the `:` ...did you forget to upload the whole message for us?

Comment: No my website is running on aws ec2 instance and console is showing me WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebsite.com:9090/' failed: this only

Comment: I just noticed something - in the script you showed, it listens on port 8090, not 9090

Comment: Sorry i changed port as well from the script. should i post my code even then?

Comment: Yes you should always post _your_ version of your code _within your question_. Questions without that info can be closed as off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]). Then we know precisely what code _you_ are are running, not just what was shown in a demo or tutorial.